# Wordpress: Using get_current_user_id() result into my DB table with an HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a plugin that contains an HTML form which sends POST data to a DB table.
It works perfectly fine excluding one thing. The logged in user's ID is not being sent to the DB table. I think it might be my IF statement just before step #2 here. I've changed it around so many times but haven't had any results. What I DO know is that this if statement works with a GET request, and It actually does give you the user's ID, but apparently not with a POST request.

```
    function ml_install() {
 // #1 CREATE TABLE
    global $wpdb;
    // creates ml_char in database if not exists
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . "ml_char"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
        `wp_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        `char_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` text NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`char_id`)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    // starts output buffering
    ob_start();
     if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $wpid = get_current_id();
    }
// #2 CREATE HTML FORM
    ?>
    <form action="#ml_form" method="post" id="ml_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="wp_id" value="<? echo $wpid; ?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="character_name" id="character_name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();
// #4 INSERT FORM DATA INTO DB
    if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["character_name"] && $_POST["wp_id"] != "" ) {
        $table = $wpdb->prefix."ml_char";
        $name = strip_tags($_POST["character_name"], "");
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'name' => $name,
                'char_id' => $wp_id
            )
        );
        $html = "<p>Greetings <strong>$name</strong>, and welcome to Hyreath.</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok people, I figured out what my issue was. I had misspelled a column name in my array. Fellow user Webcitron pointed me in the right direction.

Here is the functional code that allows me to grab someone's current Wordpress ID from the wp_users table in the WPDB and insert that into my own table. So now whenever a user comes to my website and creates new characters, all those characters will belong to that specific user, instead of not belonging to anyone. I really hope this helps someone out.

[image: HTML FORM]

[image: plugin code from head to toe]

[image: phpmyadmin result set]

Comment: https://blog.samelh.com/2015/08/13/create-mysql-database-table-wordpress-insert-data-wpdb-html-form/ I pretty much copied and altered this code to my needs. It was a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

In execute of sql query you need to pass third argument in query arguments array :) looks like you forget about that :)

Comment: I see what you're talking about. However, Only two things are actually being sent. The user's name of choice and their Wordpress ID. The third value is the character ID which my DB table automatically increments when data is inserted. I'm sorry I should have mentioned that earlier.  Thank you webcitron for your feedback!